# Remove duplicate objects from an array but merge nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Currently have an array of objects which contain game releases. However game releases can happen on multiple platforms and these appear as separate objects within the array. I'm looking to remove duplicate games by comparing the game id but merge the platforms object

I have tried using the reduce function which successfully removes duplicate objects by game id but I'm unable to adapt this to merge platforms

```
const filteredArr = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const x = acc.find(item => item.game.id === current.game.id);

  if (!x) {
    return acc.concat([current]);
  } else {
    return acc;
  }
}, []);
```

Current Array:

```
const data = [{
  "id": 157283,
  "date": 1553212800,
  "game": {
    "id": 76882,
    "name": "Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice",
    "popularity": 41.39190295640344
  },
  "human": "2019-Mar-22",
  "m": 3,
  "platform": {"id": 48, "name": "PlayStation 4"},
  "region": 8,
  "y": 2019
}, {
  "id": 12,
  "date": 1553212800,
  "game": {
    "id": 76832,
    "name": "Spiderman",
    "popularity": 41.39190295640344
  },
  "human": "2019-Mar-22",
  "m": 3,
  "platform": {"id": 6, "name": "PC (Microsoft Windows)"},
  "region": 8,
  "y": 2019
}, {
  "id": 157283,
  "date": 1553212800,
  "game": {
    "id": 76882,
    "name": "Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice",
    "popularity": 41.39190295640344
  },
  "human": "2019-Mar-22",
  "m": 3,
  "platform": {"id": 48, "name": "Xbox"},
  "region": 8,
  "y": 2019
}]
```

Expected format after merge:

```
[{
  "id": 157283,
  "date": 1553212800,
  "game": {
    "id": 76882,
    "name": "Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice",
    "popularity": 41.39190295640344
  },
  "human": "2019-Mar-22",
  "m": 3,
  "platforms": ["PlayStation", "Xbox"],
  "region": 8,
  "y": 2019
}, {
  "id": 12,
  "date": 1553212800,
  "game": {
    "id": 76832,
    "name": "Spiderman",
    "popularity": 41.39190295640344
  },
  "human": "2019-Mar-22",
  "m": 3,
  "platforms": ["Playstation"],
  "region": 8,
  "y": 2019
}]
```

Comment: What should happen if the released date for different platforms differs? In this case "Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice" released their game on multiple platforms at the same time. But it is not uncommon to release a game later for certain platforms. Take for example "Diablo 3", released on Windows and OS X in 2012, PS3 in 2013, PS4 in 2014 and Switch in 2018.

Comment: Good point, i think a simple operater will fix that usecase. ```const x = acc.find(item => item.game.id === current.game.id && item.releaseDate == current.releaseDate);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close, you just need to change the logic a bit. You can try something like the following; an example - https://repl.it/@EQuimper/ScaryBumpyCircle

```
const filteredArr = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const x = acc.find(item => item.game.id === current.game.id);

  if (!x) {
    current.platform = [current.platform]
    acc.push(current);
  } else {
    x.platform.push(current.platform);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

The return value is

```
[
  {
    "id": 157283,
    "date": 1553212800,
    "game": {
      "id": 76882,
      "name": "Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice",
      "popularity": 41.39190295640344
    },
    "human": "2019-Mar-22",
    "m": 3,
    "platform": [
      {
        "id": 48,
        "name": "PlayStation 4"
      },
      {
        "id": 48,
        "name": "Xbox"
      }
    ],
    "region": 8,
    "y": 2019
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "date": 1553212800,
    "game": {
      "id": 76832,
      "name": "Spiderman",
      "popularity": 41.39190295640344
    },
    "human": "2019-Mar-22",
    "m": 3,
    "platform": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "PC (Microsoft Windows)"
      }
    ],
    "region": 8,
    "y": 2019
  }
]
```

If you want to have just an array of platform strings, go with

```
const filteredArr = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const x = acc.find(item => item.game.id === current.game.id);

  if (!x) {
    current.platform = [current.platform.name]
    acc.push(current);
  } else {
    x.platform.push(current.platform.name);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

And now the return value is

```
[
  {
    "id": 157283,
    "date": 1553212800,
    "game": {
      "id": 76882,
      "name": "Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice",
      "popularity": 41.39190295640344
    },
    "human": "2019-Mar-22",
    "m": 3,
    "platform": [
      "PlayStation 4",
      "Xbox"
    ],
    "region": 8,
    "y": 2019
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "date": 1553212800,
    "game": {
      "id": 76832,
      "name": "Spiderman",
      "popularity": 41.39190295640344
    },
    "human": "2019-Mar-22",
    "m": 3,
    "platform": [
      "PC (Microsoft Windows)"
    ],
    "region": 8,
    "y": 2019
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could separate `platform` of the object and look if you have an object with the same `id` and add the platfor tho the array, of not create a new data set.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 157283, date: 1553212800, game: { id: 76882, name: "Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice", popularity: 41.39190295640344 }, human: "2019-Mar-22", m: 3, platform: { id: 48, name: "PlayStation 4" }, region: 8, y: 2019 }, { id: 12, date: 1553212800, game: { id: 76832, name: "Spiderman", popularity: 41.39190295640344 }, human: "2019-Mar-22", m: 3, platform: { id: 6, name: "PC (Microsoft Windows)" }, region: 8, y: 2019 }, { id: 157283, date: 1553212800, game: { id: 76882, name: "Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice", popularity: 41.39190295640344 }, human: "2019-Mar-22", m: 3, platform: { id: 48, name: "Xbox" }, region: 8, y: 2019 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { platform, ...o }) => {
        var temp = r.find(({ id }) => id === o.id);
        if (!temp) r.push(temp = { ...o, platforms: [] });
        temp.platforms.push(platform);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look:

```js
const data = [    {        "id": 157283,
        "date": 1553212800,
        "game": {
            "id": 76882,
            "name": "Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice",
            "popularity": 41.39190295640344
        },
        "human": "2019-Mar-22",
        "m": 3,
        "platform": {
            "id": 48,
            "name": "PlayStation 4"
        },
        "region": 8,
        "y": 2019
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "date": 1553212800,
        "game": {
            "id": 76832,
            "name": "Spiderman",
            "popularity": 41.39190295640344
        },
        "human": "2019-Mar-22",
        "m": 3,
        "platform": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "PC (Microsoft Windows)"
        },
        "region": 8,
        "y": 2019
    },{        "id": 157283,
    "date": 1553212800,
    "game": {
        "id": 76882,
        "name": "Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice",
        "popularity": 41.39190295640344
    },
    "human": "2019-Mar-22",
    "m": 3,
    "platform": {
        "id": 48,
        "name": "Xbox"
    },
    "region": 8,
    "y": 2019
},
]

const filteredArr = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const x = acc.find(item => item.game.id === current.game.id);
    if (!x) {
      current.platform = [current.platform.name]
      return acc.concat([current]);
    } else {
      x.platform.push(current.platform.name);
      return acc;
    }
  }, []);
console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, using `forEach` instead of `reduce`. This makes use of a lookup hash that makes if faster for larger amounts of data then using `find`.

```js
const data = [{"id": 157283, "date": 1553212800, "game": {"id": 76882, "name": "Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice", "popularity": 41.39190295640344}, "human": "2019-Mar-22", "m": 3, "platform": {"id": 48, "name": "PlayStation 4"}, "region": 8, "y": 2019}, {"id": 12, "date": 1553212800, "game": {"id": 76832, "name": "Spiderman", "popularity": 41.39190295640344}, "human": "2019-Mar-22", "m": 3, "platform": {"id": 6, "name": "PC (Microsoft Windows)"}, "region": 8, "y": 2019}, {"id": 157283, "date": 1553212800, "game": {"id": 76882, "name": "Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice", "popularity": 41.39190295640344}, "human": "2019-Mar-22", "m": 3, "platform": {"id": 48, "name": "Xbox"}, "region": 8, "y": 2019}];

let result = {};

data.forEach(({platform, ...release}) => {
  release.platforms = [platform.name];

  const releaseLookup = result[release.game.id];
  if (!releaseLookup) {
    result[release.game.id] = release;
  } else {
    releaseLookup.platforms.push(...release.platforms);
  }
});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```