# JS Array of Objects - Remove Duplicates and Merge nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

still learning JS and I have been struggling with this one problem for a bit and found a similar solution here on Stack Overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890433/remove-duplicate-objects-from-an-array-but-merge-nested-objects) which I tried to model my solution after, but I cant seem to figure it out for my use case.. so would appreciate advice on how I can fix the code I have or even just some help in the right direction

So I am trying to remove duplicates from an array of objects (see below) based on "objectID" and merge the nested "hierarchicalCategories" at each level (lvl0,lvl1,lvl2) into an array if they are unique.

```js
let objArray = [
  {
  "objectID": "1234",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": "Women's"

  }
},
{
  "objectID": "1234",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": "Women's",
    "lvl1": "Women's > Jewelry",
    "lvl2": "Women's > Jewelry > New"
  }
},
 {
  "objectID": "1234",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": "New",
    "lvl1": "New > Jewelry"
  }
},
{
  "objectID": "5678",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": "Men's",
    "lvl1": "Men's > Shoes",

  }
},
{
  "objectID": "5678",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": "New",
    "lvl1": "New > Shoes"
  }
}
]
```

The expected result should look like this: with one instance of each "objectID" and then merged "hierarchicalCategories" if there is a unique value at each level

```js
let newArray = [
 {
  "objectID": "1234",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": ["Women's","New"],
    "lvl1": ["Women's > Jewelry","New > Jewelry"],
    "lvl2": ["Women's > Jewelry > New"]
  }
},
{
  "objectID": "5678",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": ["Men's", "New"],
    "lvl1": ["Men's > Shoes","New > Shoes"]
  }
}
]
```

Here is the code I using which works to a degree but doesn't fully work. Basically at each level (lvl0,lvl1,lvl2), I am creating an array and then only pushing if it is not previously included. However if there is no level defined as in `"objectID": "5678"`which doesn't have a `"lvl2"` defined in any of the duplicates there will be a empty array in the filtered array in that slot which I do not want, but seemingly unable to fix it without breaking it entirely. Also open to other suggestions + learnings to improve the code or other ways to go about it.

```js
const filteredArr = objArray.reduce((acc, current) => {
    const x = acc.find(item => item.objectID === current.objectID);
    if (!x) {

        current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0 ? current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0 = [current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0] : current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0 = []
        current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1 ? current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1 = [current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1] : current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1 = []
        current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2 ? current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2 = [current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2] : current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2 = []

        acc.push(current)

    } else {

        if (current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0 && !x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0.includes(current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0)) {
            x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0.push(current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0)
        }
        if (current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1 && !x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1.includes(current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1)) {
            x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1.push(current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1)
        }
        if (current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2 && !x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2.includes(current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2)) {
            x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2.push(current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2)
        }

    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

I am getting this in response as you can see the empty array at lvl2

```js
[
 {
  "objectID": "1234",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": ["Women's","New"],
    "lvl1": ["Women's > Jewelry","New > Jewelry"],
    "lvl2": ["Women's > Jewelry > New"]
  }
},
{
  "objectID": "5678",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": ["Men's", "New"],
    "lvl1": ["Men's > Shoes","New > Shoes"],
    "lvl2": []
  }
}
]
```

Thank you for anyone willing to help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but I think the use of `Map` and `Set` can help to group things and make them unique:

```js
let objArray = [{"objectID": "1234","hierarchicalCategories": {"lvl0": "Women's"}},{"objectID": "1234","hierarchicalCategories": {"lvl0": "Women's","lvl1": "Women's > Jewelry","lvl2": "Women's > Jewelry > New"}},{"objectID": "1234","hierarchicalCategories": {"lvl0": "New","lvl1": "New > Jewelry"}},{"objectID": "5678","hierarchicalCategories": {"lvl0": "Men's","lvl1": "Men's > Shoes",}},{"objectID": "5678","hierarchicalCategories": {"lvl0": "New","lvl1": "New > Shoes"}}];

let map = new Map(objArray.map(o => [o.objectID, {}] ));
for (let obj of objArray) {
    let cats = map.get(obj.objectID);
    for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(obj.hierarchicalCategories)) {
        cats[key] = (cats[key] || new Set).add(val);
    }
}
let result = Array.from(map.entries(), ([objectId, cats]) => ({ 
    objectId, 
    hierarchicalCategories: Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(cats).map(([k, v]) => 
        [k, [...v]]
    )) 
}));

console.log(result);
```

### Explanation

First a Map is created, keyed by `objectID`, with corresponding values initialised to empty objects. The Map constructor gets a list of [key, value] pairs and it will create the Map from that. It will not complain about the duplicate keys provided to it.

Then for each object in the input array, the corresponding object from the map is retrieved and assigned to `cats`. The first time it will be an empty object. Then the `hierarchicalCategories` from the input object are added to `cats`. While doing this, it is verified whether the key (like "lvl2") already exists in `cats`. If not, then `cats[key]` is undefined, and only then the `||` operator will evaluate the right operand, and so a Set is created. Otherwise we know that it already is a Set. And we add the value (like "Woman's") to that Set. The advantage of using a Set is that duplicates will be ignored.

So that is what the first `for` loop does. It essentially translates the input to a structure that will deal with grouping and duplicates in an efficient way.

Then the last part of the code will turn this information into the desired output structure.

`map.entries` will give the key/value combinations it has. Now the value parts are no longer *empty* objects, because we added data to them in the previous loop. Those are those `cats` objects that may have several "lvl" keys and associated Sets.

`Array.from` will allow us to iterate those `map.entries()` and do something with each of those in a mapper-callback function. That callback function returns an object for each entry. It is surrounded by parentheses to avoid that the JS parser misinterprets the braces as a code block (it would in fact complain about it).

With `Object.entries` we look up each of the Sets, and map those to standard arrays, using `[...v]`. `Object.fromEntries` combines that back into an object (it's the reverse of `Object.entries).

Comment: this is awesome, works great, but would you mind explaining how this works in a bit more detail? Trying to just understand a bit more so I can continue to learn

Comment: @trincot your implementation does not work in my editor.However to understand this solution,we Need to know new type of object `Map` & `Set`; [read the doc](https://javascript.info/map-set)

Comment: @MuhammadAmirozzamanNiaz, at the end of 2019, with EcmaScript2019 released last June, we cannot really argue that `Map` and `Set` are new. They were available since EcmaScript2015. It is more indication that your editor is not up to speed with the developments of the last four years.

Comment: @trincot first time to anyone is always new mate.you are right that those are not new.I think you understand my point.And my nodejs version is 10.16.3

Answer (score 0):

I like it simple.

```
const myArray = [{},{}];
const myArrayMirror = [...myArray];

const sortedArray = myArray.filter(originalObj, originalIndex => {
    let objIsDuplicate = false;
    myArrayMirror.forEach(duplicate, duplicateIndex => {
        if (duplicateIndex > originalIndex && originalObj === duplicate) {
            objIsDuplicate = true;
        }
    });
    return objIsDuplicate;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
const objArray = [YOUR_OBJECTS_LIVE_HERE]

const mapWithUniqueObjs = new Map()

// loop over properties to set it to your map
for (let i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
  // Map's keys are always unique, so in case
  // we already have this item in the map, it will be overwritten
  uniqueObj.set(objArray[i].objectID, objArray[i])
}

// and make it an array
const arrWithUniqueObjs = [...mapWithUniqueObjs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Append this to the end of your code (where you assign filteredArray) :

```
.map(function(x) {
    if (x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2.length === 0) {
      delete x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2
    }
    if (x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1.length === 0) {
      delete x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1
    }
     if (x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0.length === 0) {
      delete x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0
    }
    return x
})
```

```js
let objArray = [
  {
  "objectID": "1234",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": "Women's"

  }
},
{
  "objectID": "1234",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": "Women's",
    "lvl1": "Women's > Jewelry",
    "lvl2": "Women's > Jewelry > New"
  }
},
 {
  "objectID": "1234",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": "New",
    "lvl1": "New > Jewelry"
  }
},
{
  "objectID": "5678",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": "Men's",
    "lvl1": "Men's > Shoes",

  }
},
{
  "objectID": "5678",
  "hierarchicalCategories": {
    "lvl0": "New",
    "lvl1": "New > Shoes"
  }
}
]

const filteredArr = objArray.reduce((acc, current) => {
    const x = acc.find(item => item.objectID === current.objectID);
    if (!x) {

        current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0 ? current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0 = [current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0] : current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0 = []
        current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1 ? current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1 = [current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1] : current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1 = []
        current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2 ? current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2 = [current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2] : current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2 = []

        acc.push(current)

    } else {

        if (current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0 && !x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0.includes(current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0)) {
            x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0.push(current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0)
        }
        if (current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1 && !x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1.includes(current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1)) {
            x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1.push(current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1)
        }
        if (current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2 && !x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2.includes(current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2)) {
            x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2.push(current.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2)
        }

    }
    return acc;
}, []).map(function(x) {
    if (x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2.length === 0) {
      delete x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl2
    }
    if (x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1.length === 0) {
      delete x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl1
    }
     if (x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0.length === 0) {
      delete x.hierarchicalCategories.lvl0
    }
    return x
})
console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a 2 step process:

1. groupBy `objectID`:

e.g transform `[{objectID: 1, ...}, {objectID: 1, ...}, {objectID: 2, ...}]`

into `[ [{objectID: 1, ...}, {objectID: 1, ...}], [{objectID: 2, ...}] ]`

2. `reduce (/deepmerge)` each group:

e.g `[{objectID: 1, ...merged props}, {objectID: 2, ...merged props}]`

[this is an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-4fmjgk) using the convenient `groupBy` of [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) and [deepmerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge)
libs

`deepmerge` is a very popular library for merging complex nested objects with/without arrays/nested arrays

Comment: I will check out some of those libraries, thank you for your insight